# Как удалить из огромной таблицы поля MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, double

Подскажите пожалуйста как удалить из таблицы на 1,5 миллиона строк, строки  где встречается в поле "category" = 'Рубрики'. В поиске phpMyAdmin выдаёт 15 строк, но при нажатии кнопки обзора вываливается ошибка 414. А при команде:

`` DELETE FROM `sone_companies` WHERE category = 'Рубрики' ``

Выдаёт пустой результат, также подскажите пожалуйста как удалить дубли по совпадению в 3-ёх полях 'current_id', 'name' и 'address'? Пробую вот так:

`` DELETE t1 FROM `sone_companies` t1, `sone_companies` t2 WHERE t1.current_id=t2.current_id AND t1.name = t2.name AND t1.address = t2.address ``

Команда зависает и ничего не происходит. Пробовал через консоль сервера.

Comment: похоже, что у вас что-то с кодировкой. Покопайте в эту сторону. Ваш `delete` должен удалять

Comment: Ты что пытаешься сделать? Как название твоих таблиц, что ты пытаешься сравнивать?

Comment: Так пробовали?
DELETE FROM `sone_companies` WHERE category LIKE N'%Рубрики%'

Answer (score 0):

1) Попробуй

```
 DELETE FROM `sone_companies` WHERE category LIKE 'Рубрики'
```

или даже

```
 DELETE FROM `sone_companies` WHERE category LIKE '%Рубрики%'
```

Comment: Затронуто 0 строк. (Запрос занял 18.2980 сек.)

Answer (score 0):

У тебя таблица ненормализована, одинаковые id.  По второй части твоего вопроса ответ такой, если речи идет об удалении совпадений:

```
DELETE   FROM sone_companies WHERE exists
(SELECT current_id, address, name  COUNT(current_id) FROM sone_companies 
WHERE 
sone_companies.current_id=current_id GROUP BY  
current_id, address, name having count(current_id)>1
AND count(address)>1 AND count(name )>1)
```

Хотя конечно вместо прямого сравнения можно и лучше для строк использовать LIKE как было описано выше

Comment: Выдаёт ошибку
```#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'COUNT(`current_id`) FROM `sone_companies` WHERE `sone_companies.current_id` = `' at line 2```

Comment: Тип таблицы: InnoDB
Коировка: utf8_general_ci

Comment: Надеюсь все получилось